# How to write Jags code when data is categorical?

Tags: r, jags

I'm trying to run jags and I am not sure about my Jags code.
Any advice or feedback would be appreciated.
[image]

```
        n=number of subjects (N=1000)
        i=number of items(questions) (I=42)
        m= number of attempts (M=5)
```

As you can see the screenshot of my data, it is categorical(or ordinal).

```
        1 means : p1[n,i] 
        2 means : (1-p1[n,i])*p2[n,i] 
        3 means :(1-p1[n,i])(1-p2[n,i])*p3[n,i])
        4 means :(1-p1[n,i])(1-p2[n,i])(1-p3[n,i])*p4[n,i]
        5 means : (1-p1[n,1])(1-p2[n,i])(1-p3[n,i])(1-p4[n,i])
```

I referred to the book titled 'Doing Bayesian analysis' and wrote Jags code as below.

```
    linear<-function(){   
     for(n in 1:N){ ## number of subjects (N=1000)
      for(i in 1:I){ ## number of items (I=42)
       responses[n,i]~dcat(prob[n,i,1:5]) 
      }
     } 

 for(n in 1:N){ 
    for(i in 1:I){  
     prob[n,i,1]<-p[n,i,1] ## first attempt 
     prob[n,i,2]<-prod(1-p[n,i,1:1])*p[n,i,2]
     prob[n,i,3]<-prod(1-p[n,i,1:2])*p[n,i,3]
     prob[n,i,4]<-prod(1-p[n,i,1:3])*p[n,i,4]
     prob[n,i,5]<-prod(1-p[n,i,1:4]) 
    }
   }
```

However, when I looked at other resources regarding ordinal data, they wrote like below (and I adapted my code)

```
 for(n in 1:N){ 
  for(i in 1:I){
   responses[n,i] ~ dcat(prob[n,i,1:M[i]) 
   }
  } 
 }

  for(n in 1:N){
   for (i in 1:I){ 
    prob[n, i, 1] <- p[n, i, 1] 
   }
    for (m in 2:(M[i]-1)){ 
     prob[n,i,m]<-prod(1-p[n,i,1:(m-1)])*p[n,i,m]
     }
     prob[n,i,5]<-prod(1-p[n,i,1:4])
    }

     * for(n in 1:N){
        for(i in 1:9){
          for(m in 1:4){
          logit(p[n,i,m])<-lambda0[i]+lambda1[i]*alpha[n,1,m]*Q[i,1]
          }
         }
        }*
```

I am not sure which one is right. Are there any other (right??) ways to do it?

Another problem is that when I run Jags with the second way, it gives me error
'unknown variable i' (which refers to *) and I don't know how to tackle this issue. I can't use for(i in 1:I) because logit only applies to when i is 1~9.

Please provide me with any feedback or comments.
Thank you

Comment: Please use `dput()` rather than screenshots to provide your data.  You're far more likely to get help if you do.  Secondly, code without context isn't mraningful.  What do your variables mean? What model are you trying to fit?  Is the code you've provided a JAGS model specification or R code?  (They're similar, but not the same.) If you don't tell us that, there's litle we can do.  Finally, if there's something I don't understand, I simplify the problem until I can get a handle on it.  If you're unsure how to write JAGS code, is an Nx9x4 problem the best place to start?